# Why is Visual Studio adding spaces to connection strings during a *Schema Compare* aka .scmp files?

Tags: sql-server-data-tools, microsoft-data-sqlclient

Visual Studio is adding random spaces in my connection string when doing a schema compare. Anyone know why?

`ConnectionString-xml-element-diff.txt`:

```
old: MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=10;TrustServerCertificate=False;
new: Multiple Active Result Sets=False;Connect Timeout=10;Trust Server Certificate=False;
```

Above is the short version, rant and details to follow (details I already understand, that you don't need to explain in your answer).

**Details and History**

1. The only reason I have the `*.scmp` files is because Visual Studio doesn't have a decent set of defaults when doing SQL Server schema compare (running app environment database like MyAppDev or MyAppTest01) vs git's app schema.
2. VS tooling churns these files all the time, randomly. Why can't they use a `.yaml` file that doesn't contain all these .NET types that have nothing to do with the task I'm trying to accomplish.

Why (1)? It defaults to ALL objects in SQL Server. I get these tools could be used by DBAs, sure, but I think MOST folks using Visual Studio are devs! (I.e. NOT DBAs primarily!) So why does this *by default* try to compare and deploy disk partition schemes and AD service account permissions when I don't have access to any of that stuff? I have to turn off a TON of object types for every DB schema project I add with Visual Studio (or copy `.scmp` file from a prior project).

`git-diff.txt`:

```
diff --git a/data/mssql/sql-compare-schema/MyTeam_SampleApp to SampleApp.uat.scmp b/data/mssql/sql-compare-schema/MyTeam_SampleApp to SampleApp.uat.scmp
index ab013241c..1e0b8a7a0 100644
--- a/data/mssql/sql-compare-schema/MyTeam_SampleApp to SampleApp.uat.scmp  
+++ b/data/mssql/sql-compare-schema/MyTeam_SampleApp to SampleApp.uat.scmp  
@@ -9,7 +9,7 @@
   </SourceModelProvider>
   <TargetModelProvider>
     <ConnectionBasedModelProvider>
-      <ConnectionString>Data Source=SampleApp-uat.internal.mycorp.com;Initial Catalog=MyTeam_SampleAppOffice;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=10;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False</ConnectionString>
+      <ConnectionString>Data Source=SampleApp-uat.internal.mycorp.com;Initial Catalog=MyTeam_SampleAppOffice;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;Multiple Active Result Sets=False;Connect Timeout=10;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False</ConnectionString>
     </ConnectionBasedModelProvider>
   </TargetModelProvider>
   <SchemaCompareSettingsService>
@@ -338,7 +342,7 @@
       </PropertyElementName>
       <PropertyElementName>
         <Name>TargetConnectionString</Name>
-        <Value>Data Source=SampleApp-uat.internal.mycorp.com;Initial Catalog=MyTeam_SampleAppOffice;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Connect Timeout=10;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;Application Name="Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, Schema Compare"</Value>
+        <Value>Data Source=SampleApp-uat.internal.mycorp.com;Initial Catalog=MyTeam_SampleAppOffice;Integrated Security=True;Persist Security Info=False;Pooling=False;Multiple Active Result Sets=False;Connect Timeout=10;Encrypt=False;Trust Server Certificate=False;Application Name="Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools, Schema Compare"</Value>
       </PropertyElementName>
       <PropertyElementName>
         <Name>TreatVerificationErrorsAsWarnings</Name>
@@ -1156,560 +1160,604 @@
     <Filter>Equals_Objects,Not_Supported_Deploy</Filter>
   </SchemaCompareViewSettings>
   <ExcludedSourceElements>
-    <SelectedItem Type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlProcedure, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
+    <SelectedItem Type="Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql.SchemaModel.SqlProcedure, Microsoft.Data.Tools.Schema.Sql, Version=16.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
       <Name>dbo</Name>
       <Name>sp_generate_merge</Name>
     </SelectedItem>
```

Comment: 2.b. Better then .yaml would be .toml, since that is what Python picked for it's project file, and what non-trivial enterprise doesn't use some Python.

Comment: Rant continued: I've had 2 junior developers wipe out all but 1 user account on the production MSSQL server because they got the object type filters wrong when doing simple deployments.  I mention this because professionals use these tools and they can have really bad consequences of "bad defaults".

Comment: @marc_s In your edit why did you change markdown H2 (aka `## Details`) to bold text (aka `**`)?